# Is it possible to create a Jquery object from an arbitrary string with HTML e.g. var $newlink = $('<a>new link</a>')

Tags: javascript, jquery

So not an object attached to the dom yet, but I wish to make an object just by passing a HTML string and retain reference to that element once its inserted into the dom.

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself, as the question is correct, `$newlink` would be a jQuery object. Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8w7TW/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var link = $( '<a></a>').html( str );
link.appendTo( document.body );
```

And you can still use `link`.

Comment: without an href="#" or href="jvascript:void(0)", a tag is not so correct

Answer (score 1):

You culd also do this:

```
    $('<a/>',{  
        id:'test', //add ID
        text: str, //add Text
        href:'http://www.yourlinkhere.com', //link target
        css:{                
            'color':'#000' //whatever style u want
        }        
    }).appendTo('body'); // append to whatever element u want in this case 'body'
```

or attach it to a variable

```
var link = $('<a/>',{text:str});
```